# regex explained in english

Tags: regex, pcre

I have looked [here](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) and from what I understand the following regex simply means "any unicode character sequence". Can someone confirm this please?

Current Regex: /^(?>\P{M}\p{M}*)+$/u

Also if I read the manual it says

a) \P{M} = \PM

b) (?>\PM\pM*) = \X

So with these two things in hand, can I not simplify the regex to?:

Proposed Regex: /^\X+$/u

Which I still don't actually understand...

Comment: Ok, according to the anual you are right. But, what is the question?

Comment: [Me reading regex documentation](http://thejoysofcode.tumblr.com/post/35331265331/when-i-am-forced-to-read-regex-documentation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `\P{M}\p{M}*` could be simplified to `\X`, but not all languages support `\X` while (in my experience) `\P{M}` and `\p{M}` are supported more frequently.

For example, Java's and .NET's regex engines do not support `\X` (Perl does, of course...).

More info, see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Answer (score 2):

```
^            # start of string followed by 
(?>          # an independent (non-backtracking) capturing group containing 
    \P{M}    # a single unicode character which is not in the `Mark` category
    \p{M}*   # 0 or more characters in the `Mark` category
)+           # with this capturing group repeated 1 or more times
$            # the end-of-line
```

Whereas `^\X+$` contains no capturing group; the `\P{M}\p{M}*` is otherwise equivalent.

Comment: This was also a very helpful answer, but I can only accept one and the answer by Bart is more what I was looking for.